# disable media library tab for non admins in uploader screen

Tags: wordpress

I am developing a plugin in which I am required to allow front end users to upload media, which I am able to do. But I don't want to let them sneak into media library which comes as tab with uploader screen.

I tried something like :

```
 function remove_medialibrary_tab($tabs) {
        if ( !current_user_can( 'administrator' ) ) {
            unset($tabs['library']);
            return $tabs;
        }
        else
        {
            return $tabs;
        }
    }
    add_filter('media_upload_tabs','remove_medialibrary_tab');
```

But seems this filter is deprecated and no more works. Any other way out?

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
function remove_medialibrary_tab($tabs) {
    if ( !current_user_can( 'administrator' ) ) {
        unset($tabs["mediaLibraryTitle"]);
    }
    return $tabs;
}
add_filter('media_view_strings', 'remove_medialibrary_tab');
```